# Best way to find needed element in array of objects

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have array of objects of my class. My class have variable for name that is unique for every object created. Now, I want to find, say, object in array that has a name "test". I wanted to try something like creating second array with just names as elements and when I create new object in my first array to create object in second array so that they share index number. Something like this:

```
arrayOfObjects.push(new obj("test"));
arrayOfNames.push("test");

function findIndexNumberOf(name){
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++){
        if(arrayOfNames[i] === name)
        return i;
    }
}
```

But I think that this is pretty robust solution so I'm wondering is there better/smarter/faster way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find **the index of an item**, it's generally the easiest to use `indexOf`:

```
const haystack = ["this", "is", "a", "test"];
const needle = "this";

const result = haystack.indexOf(needle);
```

However, this will work with primitive types. Assuming you have an array of objects, comparing them will require a different approach. Here are some one-liners:

```
const haystack = [new String("this"), new String("is"), new String("a"), new String("test")];
const needle = "test";

const result1 = haystack.indexOf(haystack.filter(item => item == needle)[0]);
const result2 = haystack.indexOf(haystack.filter(item => item.toString() === needle.toString())[0]);
const result3 = haystack.map(item => item.toString()).indexOf(needle.toString());
const result4 = haystack.indexOf(haystack.find(item => item.toString() === needle.toString()));
```

`result1` filters the haystack using the `==` operator, thus ignoring the fact that the compared values are actually different types. The first element of the filtered array is then fed to `indexOf`. This will allow you to use a primitive string as the needle and search through a haystack of objects.

`result2` uses the same approach, but casts both compared values to a primitive string, making sure they're both of the same type. This will allow you to mix and match primitives and `String` objects liberally, both in the haystack and needle.

`result3` maps all haystack values to primitive strings and then uses `indexOf` on that new array of primitives. I also added `toString` to the needle to ensure it's also a primitive. This works similar to your approach, but the mapping is run every time you search for a needle. This is probably suboptimal.

`result4` uses `Array.prototype.find` to locate the target object on the haystack and then feeds the result to `indexOf`. This might be the fastest, but I have no empirical data to back this up.

Now, in case you wanted to find **the actual item**, not just its index, you're best off using `Array.prototype.find`:

```
const result = haystack.find(item => item == needle);
```

or, in case both are `String` objects:

```
const result = haystack.find(item => item.toString() === needle.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you!! Fourth way was absolutely perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find method of Arrays object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const myObject = arr.find(o => o.name === 'the_name_you_search');
```

Comment: This one has no IE support :(